# Best way to return the string

Tags: c#, properties

I may get negative marks for this but still getting some comments from experts or suggestions is more knowledge to me, so here is my question.

Here I am returning a string

```
public static string mystring()
{ 
    return "test";
}
```

Is there any best way to return the string or what is the draw back of my return?

Comment: It is as good as any other I think. If it isn't just a constant.

Comment: Are you just going to return the same string every time you call this method?

Comment: Personally, I would ad a verb to the method's name. E.g. `GetMyString()`.

Comment: @BoltClock,that's correct just assume am going to return the same string everytime.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys ,i use some times properties to return the method. just want to know what's the xpert way, thanks for all your comments

Comment: Really, personally, I would use a property in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private const string _myString = "MyString";
public string GetMyString()
{
    return _myString;
}
```

Comment: I had expected the answer with highest vote will have some technical explanation...

Comment: why not use `public const string _myString = "MyString";`
this is unneeded use of a property.

Comment: Additionally, I would have expected that this answer complies to the .NET naming conventions ;-)

Answer (score 3):

will this string ever change its source?
if you are sure it will always be hardcoded, just use constant.

```
 const string mystring = "test";
```

if it might get its value from somewhere else in your class. property will be better

```
 public string MyString
{
    get {return "test";}
}
```

use the function only if this value will need some complex logic in the future. like been taken from database inputed by user and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that there is a problem with it. I would do it the same way.

A second way would be to use properties:

```
public static string mystring {
   get { return "test"; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a constant and return that from method.

if you are returning same value from multiple methods, updating the value at one place will be easier than to update in each method.

Comment: make sense to me,if am going to change my string value

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is no problem.

However, it's preferable to stick to conventions, and use a constant.
I'm sure there's no need to explain the need to stick to conventions and standards!

EDIT: If you feel that one day there may be a need to use some internal logic before returning the string, then perhaps using a method is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a constant like `myString`, instead of mystring function. So whenever you want to use this string just call that constant.

```
public const string myString = "test";
```